# Build fails with proguard obfuscation inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

If I run a build with proguard obfuscation inside a docker container, it fails with an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.wvengen:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.14:proguard (default) on project -testnfohandler-impl: Obfuscation failed (result=137) -> [Help 1]
```

However, if the same is run on the host(i.e. not inside docker container), it succeeds.

I'm unable to find what exactly causing this failure inside a docker container.

Could you please guide me what are the things I should try out with docker container to resolve or identify the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to short of memory for maven. I increased memory for maven using MAVEN_OPTS and it resolved issue.

Reference - https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin/issues/120